# Email Intent -EMAIL_TEXT not load table

Tags: android

**How to set Table data i.e .. in email body part**

```
    Intent emailIntent=new Intent();
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                            "");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(strBodyTable));

    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,"");
```

In Email attachment not showing table and inner  data properly (With border table style) problem

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setType("text/html");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "testing email send.");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(strBodyTable));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email to Friend"));
```

Comment: Html content showing but table and table with color not showing propelry only text show